# Cannot symlink onto a NAS in Catalina

Tags: ios, symlink, macos-catalina, nas, openmediavault

Per [This link](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-7392#relocate), I want to backup my iPhone onto a NAS since my iPhone is almost full and has the same 120gb storage as my MacBook Air and Mac mini. I have set up a dedicated SMB share on my OMV nas, but when I try to link that folder to the iPhone backup folder (/Users//Library/Application Support/MobileSync) as root, it says operation not permitted. Is there a way to accomplish my goal without disabling SIP?

Answer (score 1):

No. Apple is really strict with that sort of stuff.. System Integrity Protection isn't that big of a deal as long as you  only install applications from developers you trust. Seriously. disabling SIP will make your machine more vulnerable, but its really there to not allow malware to access/modify sensitive stuff like your backups

Comment: And I assume there's no way to back up iPhone to my NAS by any other means?

Comment: no. you cannot. in my opinion, as long as you aren't installing risky apps from risky sites your going to be fine.

Comment: With SIP disabled in my Mac mini, the operation doesn't work. csrutil status gives 
Configuration:
 Apple Internal: disabled
 Kext Signing: disabled
 Filesystem Protections: disabled
 Debugging Restrictions: disabled
 DTrace Restrictions: disabled
 NVRAM Protections: disabled
 BaseSystem Verification: disabled

What do I need to do? The drive I am trying to link is currently mounted and works fine

Comment: So wait, form what im picking up, your trying to make a backup disk using a external drive for your iPhone back ups?

Comment: Yes. I don't want to pay for iCloud storage when I have a perfectly capable NAS, and my internet provider has data caps I don't want to run into. Doing a symlink should make this possible but I'm not sure how to get around MacOS's walls.

Comment: What about some Automator script that performed a copy function to the external drive, then deleted the file from the originating machine?

Comment: That should work. But if you want to make it more intuitive without the wires, you can always make it send it to NAS...  But like I said before, the script might not be allowed to edit anything inside of that backup file cause Apple deemed it as "Sensitive"

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to make the symlink itself work? Even with SIP disabled I can't execute the command

Comment: Yes, I know what a symbolic link is. But here's the thing, we're not copying the file path. rather taking the whole file and placing it in ur NAS.